"Object" Texture Coordinate option showing a blank texture
Currently watching some YT tutorials and having a weird issue where selecting the "Object" option from the Texture Coordinate node is not properly working on my end.
I have tried recalculating normals and checking if the scale if off, but I can't think of any other reason why is it not working.


